# Filter on Azure stream analytics using MetaDataPropertyValue

Tags: azure, transformation, azure-stream-analytics

```
SELECT  
    GetMetadataPropertyValue("deviceinputstream", '[User].[productFilter]') AS prodFilter
INTO 
    "outputstream" 
FROM 
    "inputstream"
```

I'm trying to get meta data property values to filter the data.  Using the query defined above I'm able to get the meta data property but how do I filter the input stream based on this?

"input stream" is an iot-hub and gets data from a number of devices.  This meta data property is what distinguishes different products.  What should I write in the where clause?

I tried using  `WHERE prodfilter = 'product1`'` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `prodFilter` like this:

```
SELECT  
    GetMetadataPropertyValue("deviceinputstream", '[User].[productFilter]') AS prodFilter
INTO outputstream
FROM inputstream
WHERE prodFilter = 'product1'
```

, then the `prodFilter` in WHERE is not yet defined.
You should either use the original expression, like:

```
SELECT  
    GetMetadataPropertyValue("deviceinputstream", '[User].[productFilter]') AS prodFilter
INTO outputstream 
FROM inputstream
WHERE
    GetMetadataPropertyValue("deviceinputstream", '[User].[productFilter]') = 'product1'
```

or better yet filter in different step:

```
WITH step1 AS (
    SELECT  
        GetMetadataPropertyValue("deviceinputstream", '[User].[productFilter]') AS prodFilter
    FROM inputstream
```

)

```
SELECT *
INTO outputstream
FROM step1
WHERE prodFilter = 'product1'
```